# Js Library into browser

Tags: javascript

Since web browsers want to make the web faster.

I know google has his hosted libraries. But why not integrate them on the browser directly?

Problem nowadays is that if you navigate from one page that has jQuery to another page with jQuery since the url is different that same js is cached for that particular url. So loading time takes up longer while navigating between pages with same libraries.

Can't they make something that saves most known libraries in the browser so that when you load jQuery or jQuery-min it searches for it on the browser first.

**Pros**

-Faster navigation on the web.
-Makes 1 http request less if he finds the library to load.

**Cons**

Some problems that can occur with that is versions. Since most files have names like `jquery.min.js` we can't simply load them if they have the same name, on the other hand some have `/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` So the browser could try to find out the version with the url. If the browser couldn't find version than it would simply load the file.

What do you think ? Any suggestions on how this could work ? Any other cons ?

**Edit1:** I'm aware of CDNs. I'm only suggesting a way slightly faster than CDNs and doing one http request on the same process.

Comment: This is really a great idea which should be brought in for browsers for desktop as well as mobile phones, wherein for mobile devices a huge number of js lib could be 1-2mb but that would save a lot of network bandwidth and enhance the user-experience

Comment: Such thing is called caching. Popular libraries hosted on CDNs are typically cached already.

Comment: If you refresh your cache in jquery.com it would still load the library so you still have to load it once to put it in cache

Comment: @Marcio The browser would have to do the same thing to make sure it always had all the latest versions and all the new libraries in its cache. Hoping that browsers provide larger and better caching mechanisms - already underway - will yield better results in my opinion; Or convincing everybody to use the hosted versions to make better use of the already available cache. Like the idea though.

Comment: How would you decide which libraries you preinstall with the browser [jsdb.io][1] currently lists ~700 different JS libraries that's going to be a large addition to your installer if you add them all. 

If you don't add them all you're giving an unfair advantage to the ones you do choose which will stifle developer choice and kill innovation in the library space.

You may say but at least add jQuery it's being used by 92% of the internet but you probably could have got similar penetration numbers for prototype 10 years ago (ok, maybe not that high but it was everywhere).

  [1]: http://jsdb.io

Comment: @HelderRoem Like i said the only way i could see this work with versioning is by checking the url. And I think presaving top 50 libraries wouldn't be that much of an addition to the installer since almost all of those libraries are < 100kb it would be 5Mb max for 50 libraries. I think it's fine if we don't presave every library we know of, because  my thinking is that most known libraries are the ones who are more likely to load from one page to another again and again. But if we could presave all of them that would be even better.

Comment: @Marcio why not just use something like application cache to acheive this, it's similar functionality without giving the unfair advantage to a particular set of libs  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5

Comment: @HelderRoem Even if it worked "Cache manifest", the problem with that is that people would have to start to use it and put in their code. By modifying how browsers get the libraries/files everything would still work without developers having to change anything in their code.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be avoided by using commonly used CDNs, as you mentioned.

http://cdnjs.com/

However I think integrating them into the browser could introduce a real versioning problem.  Just think of how long in-between versions of IE.  If you had to wait that long to download and cache new versions of libraries, it would be a disaster.

Also you would have to download a large variety of libraries to have your bases covered.

Downloading libraries is typically not very slow, its the time to parse and execute it that takes longer on mobile.

Here is a great post about this topic

http://flippinawesome.org/2014/03/10/is-jquery-too-big-for-mobile/

Comment: I'm not saying it should only load them from the browser i'm only proposing a way to cache some libraries and IF he finds them he loads it from browser and if he doesn't find it than he downloads it.

Comment: It would be just a way slightly faster than CDNs. And one http request less.